# Converting Java Date to Php

Tags: java, php, date

How can I format a "Java-Date" in seconds since 1970 to an dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:SS in php. I have this date as an variable in php:

`$date = "1362065364128";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date = "1362065364128";
$phpDate = date('d.m.y H:i:s', $date/1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's called a unix timestamp, and you can pass it as the second argument to the `date` function in php-

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP method `date`, note that the three last numbers are milliseconds here, so you need to disregard them first.

```
$date = "1362065364128";
$formatted = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', intval($date) / 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP `date` function, documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)